# Responsive images in a fluid-width table (max-width)

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables, fluid-layout

Consider the following piece of code:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
div { max-width: 200px }
img { max-width: 100%  }​
```

The image will never be wider than 200px, regardless of its native size. So far so good.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/

---

However, if the parent element has its `display` set to `table`:

```css
div { max-width: 200px; display: table }
```

the image magically expands to its native width, expanding the `table` with it.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/1/

---

Same happens with an actual table: http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/2/

---

**Question:** Is this expected behavior? If so, what can be done to work around this issue?

Setting the parent's `width` (even a percentage-based width) instead of `max-width` correctly squeezes the image back into its box, but is not a solution. I need the parent to be fluid (I'm using this for the main structure of the site, so that I can have [the sidebar HTML appear after the main content in the source, but with the sidebar being fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/89GME/)).

Also, [setting `table-layout` to `fixed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147255/why-doesnt-ie-respect-table-width-with-fluid-image-child#answer-9147563) seems to have [no effect](http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/3/) here.

Comment: I'm trying to build something responsive in SharePoint 2010, which has a really nasty habit of wrapping nested tables around things. If you know of a solution to this (that works back as far as IE8) I'd love to hear about it. @pKs's solution (display:block;) fails in IE8/9 here :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that a table (or a div set to behave like a table) is not a block element, and max-width only applies to block elements.  My only suggestion to you is to wrap the table element in a div with display: block; set.

Here's the fiddle in case you're interested:  http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/4/

Comment: Thanks for your *correct* answer, but in my case this doesn't help me. Take a look at [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/659JN/). It works correctly in webkit, but nowhere else. Wrapping another element inside of it [does not help](http://jsfiddle.net/6BWCw/).

Comment: I'm begrudgingly accepting this answer, since it's correct. However, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Joseph, thank you for the acceptance.  I wish I had a solution to your problem, as I don't typically like to post "that can't be done" responses – but after some research combined with my own personal experiences, I haven't been able to come up with a good solution to your problem.  In fact, this has perplexed me quite a bit; I look forward to hearing from anyone who can solve this better than I have.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is pretty late, but found the answer, which turned out to be pretty simple and super easy, table-layout: fixed.

Found here:  http://blog.room34.com/archives/5042

Anyway, this is for those looking for an answer to this conundrum as I was.

Comment: I would briefly explain or paraphrase the article as to why `table-layout: fixed` is an answer here especially since the OP said that didn't work for him.

Comment: This only works with a specified width. The question was how to achieve this with a `max-width` set. The parent has to be fluid width.