# How to make IE 11 honour columns widths in tables when containing large images in rows?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table

The below works fine in Chrome (latest) and strangely in outdated IE versions - but in the latest IE version (11) it does not seem to behave as I would like.

In Chrome (latest) and outdated IE versions Column 1 does not change its width to accommodate the large image in Column 2, but in the latest IE version (11) it does - how to correct this?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="header">
     Column 1
  </td>
  <td class="header">
     Column 2
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="body_twenty">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Test...
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
  <td class="body_eighty">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Test...
           </td>
           <td>
              Test...
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="body_twenty">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              Test...
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
  <td class="body_eighty">
     Test...
     <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="footer">
  </td>
  <td class="footer">
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/tLfur3xz/1/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this style:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hsLcns3w/)

When you use `fixed`:

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values)

Answer (score 4):

It works if I give the image a width too by adding `img { width: 100% }`.

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tLfur3xz/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Change `max-width: 100%` to `width: 100%` for the img element.

https://jsfiddle.net/tLfur3xz/3/

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147255/why-doesnt-ie-respect-table-width-with-fluid-image-child).

> If you specify table-layout: fixed; in the table css it works.
>
> There seems to be some contradictory terminology in the standard
>   regarding table layouts. In particular, table-layout: auto; says this:
>
> > The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells
>
> The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells
>   Since the images content is unbreakable, it sets the width of the cell
>   to the size of the content. The max-width seems to be overriden by it.

However, in this case I see no difference between using max-width and width on the img element, so simply setting the width seems the better option to me.

Comment: Funny, I was about to link to the same question, but the explanation given there, doesn't suggest to use `width: 100%` but `table-layout: fixed`, like @RickHitchcock suggests.

Comment: The table-layout method seems to work better when testing across IE past and present and Chrome (latest). But appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found for MANY IE issues is this: You MUST add the following two lines in the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

This solved several problems that took up much of my time to resolve.

Comment: can you explain what this does?